# How many mirrors must a man look in before he becomes a man?

Tags: continental-philosophy, psychology, psychoanalysis, contemporary-philosophy, lacan

In Lacanian theory, the mirror stage first becomes effective when the infant ego is confronted with the possibility of another ego - an other - usually taken as the gaze of the mother; but this is but a **moment** in the life of the ego; Can this stage of mimicry & mirroring be traversed (in more minor modes) as an adult? That is the mirror stage happens not once, but again & again; with the first (traversal) being the most important, later ones less so (thus minor); to put it another way - does *remain* active as a **permanent** part/conditioning of the egos structure & formation - at times more active at other times less so - rather than a *transient* formation in the egos early life; if so, under what conditions does it *heighten* or *intensify*?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_stage) suggests that it is:

> Initially, Lacan proposed that the mirror stage was part of an infant's development from 6 to 18 months, as outlined at the Fourteenth International Psychoanalytical Congress at Marienbad in 1936. By the early 1950s, Lacan's concept of the mirror stage had evolved: he no longer considered the mirror stage as a **moment** in the life of the infant, but as representing a **permanent** structure of subjectivity, or as the paradigm of "Imaginary order".

Comment: @ Mozibur Ullah Depends on whether his ego is a sphere, a Klein bottle, a Moebius strip, or a torus :-)

Comment: but not a pyramid, cylinder or cube ;).

Comment: Is there any chance you could pose this a little more pedagogically? :)

Comment: @MoziburUllah Did you see this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22HEqRrXDlM

Comment: @user4894: I hadn't - interesting & entertaining short.

Comment: @Weissman: I thought it was fairly clear :), any better?